# errors with edit button code

Tags: php, html

Hi everyone i have a table on phpmyadmin which is displayed on my homepage.
I made different modes (add contact,edit and remove mode) for the user to add more info into the database or remove and even edit. Now the add and remove mode work perfectly but for some reason edit isnt working at all.

EDIT: The edit button is working but it isnt displaying the current data in the fields such as:

Name: Jurgen

Mobile: 48854

Right now it shows this:

Name:

Mobile:

just empty. i need it to display the current data

then the user can change what they want and click update. (the update works already and it does change the data but i need the original to show when they click edit)

Here is my homepage.php code ( i hope its the right code you need )
Once again thank you for all the help^^

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "^h1dDeN!") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("phonebook") or die(mysql_error());
    $mode = $_GET['mode'];
    $checkSql="select count(id) as eCount from address";
    $result = mysql_query($checkSql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row['eCount'] == 999) {
        $disable = 1;
    }
    switch($mode) {
        case 'add':
?>
    <h2>Add Contact</h2>
    <form name="form1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=added" method="post">
        <div align="center">
            <table class="searchable">
                <tr><td>Extension:</td><td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="ext" />
                </div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Name:</td><td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Department:</td><td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="department" />
                </div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                </div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cellphone:</td><td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" />
                </div></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> | <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add New Contact" <?php if($disable ==1){?>disabled<?php } ?>/></td></tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="added">
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
    break;
    case 'added':
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $ext = $_POST ['ext'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO address (ext, name, department ,email, phone) VALUES ('" . $ext . "','" . $name . "','" . $department . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $phone . "')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    break;

    case 'edit':
?>
    <h2>Editing: <?=$_GET['name'];?></h2>
    <form name="form1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=edited" method="post">
        <table width="399" class="searchable">
            <tr><td width="87">Extension:</td>
            <td width="551"><div align="left">
                <input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['ext'];?>" name="ext" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Name:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['name'];?>" name="name" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Department:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['department'];?>" name="department" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['email'];?>" name="email" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cellphone:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['phone'];?>" name="phone" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> |<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></td></tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edited">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id'];?>">
        </table>
    </form>
<?php 
    break;

    case 'edited':
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $ext = $_POST ['Ext'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE address SET ext = '" . $ext ."', name = '" . $name . "', department = '" . $department . "', email = '" . $email . "',, phone = '" . $phone . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    break;

    case 'remove':
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql ="delete from address where id= '" . $id ."'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    break;
```

Comment: This is a school example for code _wide_ open to SQL injection attacks. Blind trust in unsafe data transferred from a client, no validation, escaping or sanitizing of data, usage of an outdated and deprecated mysql adapter, no parameter binding, ...

Comment: About your question: do you get any entries in your http servers error log file?

Comment: in your edit part your not fetching value from database

Comment: This is going to be used a local offline network sir. @arkascha

Comment: @jothi could you assist me with it sir?

Comment: @EternalJ What difference does that make? The deprecated `mysql_...()` functions will be removed from php in future, then your implementation will break. Most attacks on such applications come from _within_ an internal network. And apart from that: implementing in a save way is not more effort than without, so why not simply _do_ it?

Comment: @arkascha i understand sir :) how would i make it secure sir?

Comment: I have fixed one issue. It now updates when the user clicks update but the only issue now is i need the current data to show when the user clicks edit and the form appears eg. Name: Jurgen, Mobile: 03023030  then they can change what they want and click update.

Comment: Why you have 2 commas in update query? `"',, phone = `

Comment: thats how i was taught sir @techie_28

Comment: Does your update query run error free?Do you see the changes in DB record?

Comment: @techie_28 yes sir it runs fine it updates with no issue. I just need the fields to show the original data before they change it and click update. so it shows Name: Jurgen before they backspace and make it Name: Michael and click update